# Can't change Facebook app site url?

Tags: facebook

Ok, so maybe I'm just going crazy, but did Facebook remove the option to edit the site url in their Developers application?

When I visit the overview of my apps (https://developers.facebook.com/apps/) and look at the summary of one of my older apps, I see the Site Url specified. When I then go to edit the app settings, there is no option to change the Site Url (in fact, it's not even mentioned in one of the three tabs!).

What did Facebook do to it? A new app I'm trying to build is giving me a "Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration." error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's still there. There's more than three tabs.

[image]

Comment: I feel like such an idiot right now! Haha...

Thanks for the help!