# How to change site url in facebook app?

Tags: facebook

I am trying to modify the Site Url settings on facebook developer but I couldn't do so. I have found these answers but it seemed that facebook has changed the design of their developer's site and the "Site Url" field is missing. I could not find "Select how your app integrates with Facebook" under the "Basic" tab also.

[Can't change Facebook app site url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6656964/cant-change-facebook-app-site-url)

[Site URL For Facebook App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9670267/site-url-for-facebook-app)

The screenshot of what I currently have is as followed:

[image]

Comment: looks like your app hasn't got any platforms configured, if you want to add a 'website' integration, add it using the 'Add Platform' button

Answer (score 1):

looks like your app hasn't got any platforms configured, if you want to add a 'website' integration, add it using the 'Add Platform' button